# Using Git Bash with Maven jvm.config on Windows

Tags: git, maven

What is the trick to getting Git Bash to work with Maven's jvm.config settings?  Anything I place in jvm.config is reported as an invalid option. If I don't change anything and run the same maven command from cmd.exe shell, there are no errors.

Git version 2.7.2-64bit installed on Windows 7. Maven version 3.3.3 or 3.3.9.

Bash error looks like:

```
$ mvn clean install
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms256m
```

jvm.config file contains only the following:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
```

Even enabling -X for maven yields no help:

```
$ mvn -X clean install
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms256m
```

Comment: Which version of Maven do you use? can you try to run in Git Bash `mvn -X clean install ` and redirect the output to a log file and may be post it here..?

Comment: I am using maven 3.3.3.  But, running with -X yields absolutely nothing:

Comment: Did you already run the script with `sh -x`?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking Michael-O, but I think the answer is no.

Comment: Can you show the content of `jvm.config` ?

Comment: I have checked on Windows with Git Version 2.7.0 it works perfect with Maven 3.3.9 ? Can you check with Maven 3.3.9 ?

Comment: the contents of jvm.config were/are in the original post above

Comment: tried maven versions 3.3.3 and 3.3.9, same effect.  Also, tried GIT release 2.7.2 and 1.9.2 (had an old version laying around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in Windows line endings in jvm.config.

Solutions:

1) Save this file in unix format (dos2unix will help)

2) Amend one line in maven startup script from `echo "$(tr -s '\r' ' ' < "$1")"`
to `echo "$(tr -s '\r\n' ' ' < "$1")"`

Comment: You are correct, this was the issue.  Thank you.  I took an alternative solution to the problem and use the utility "dos2unix" on the jvm.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add MAVEN_OPTS to maven startup script instead of using jvm.config.

Add: 
    `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx2048m`
to the beginning of `<maven_home>/bin/mvn`

Comment: MAVEN_OPTS continues to work fine, but that isn't the purpose of this question.